# how to store db value in memcache and displaying it from memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I have a database in mysql and i want to fetch data from mysql at the first time and store it in memcache.
Second time i want to fetch it from memcahce and displaying it from memcache for 2-3 minute then again from database. I am very new to memcache and expecting small example so that i can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starting with Memcache , make a simple database and insert some value in it. I am giving you the php file named it whatever you want sample_memcache.php
Note : $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname is your localhost, your database username, password and database name respectively.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <p><b>Name</b>: <input type="text" size="20" name="name" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$id = $_REQUEST['name'];
//echo $id;
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$key = md5("SELECT * FROM memc where FirstName='{$id}'");
//echo $key;
$get_result = array();
$get_result = $memcache->get($key);

if ($get_result) {
        echo "<pre>\n";
        echo "FirstName: " . $get_result['FirstName'] . "\n";
        echo "LastName: " . $get_result['LastName'] . "\n";
        echo "Age: " . $get_result['Age'] . "\n";
        echo "Retrieved From Cache\n";
        echo "</pre>\n";
} else {
        // Run the query and get the data from the database then cache it
    //echo $id;
        $query="SELECT * FROM memc where FirstName='{$id}'";
     //echo $query;
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<pre>\n";
        echo "FirstName: " . $row[1] . "\n";
        echo "LastName: " . $row[2] . "\n";
        echo "Age: " . $row[3] . "\n";
        echo "Retrieved from the Database\n";
        echo "</pre>\n";
        $memcache->set($key, $row, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 60); // Store the result of the query for 20 seconds

        mysql_free_result($result);
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it is working , now atleast i can start work on it. This is very good example for start up and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic memcache usage. Essentially what you need to do is, before retrieving a value from the database, check whether it exists already in memcache. If it does, use that value. If not, retrieve it from the database and store it in memcache with a suitable expiry time. Generally this works by creating a wrapper of some sort that you use to retrieve data.

Unless you have a more specific question, I'd suggest you start with the [Memcached introduction](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgramming). The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/memcached) also has several examples that can get you started.